# Post to facebook works, but login with facebook throws error

Tags: angularjs, oauth

I am usin https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook directive for my Angular application. The facebook share dialog works fine but when I try to logIn with facebook, I get a `Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.` error. I don't know why this is happening, as I'm using the same app Id for both of the functions but, the login still doesn't work, and I tried almost evrything with the app url in the facebook App settings, and the share dialog is working while login is not. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Like I said facebook share is working but login not. So I am concluding that there is nothing wrong with my URLs in App settings.

Comment: did you discover how to make it work, @user2315366?